# Cannot load ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to load ggplot2 and got the following error message.

```
library(ggplot2)
sh: otool: command not found
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: system2("otool", c("-L", shQuote(DLL)), stdout = TRUE)
  error: error in running command
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Mac OSX, you can resolve this issue by deleting X11 (Applications > Utilities > X11), as well as the folder in "/opt" (from Finder, go to folder > /opt). Then, reinstall X11 (http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac). Restart your R session and you should be good to go.